# How to find the eigenvalues of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The question is
Let $T$ be a linear transformation on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n .$ If $T^{n-1}(\mathbf{v}) \neq \mathbf{0}$ but $T^{n}(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{0},$ for some $\mathbf{v} \in V,$ then show that $\left\{\mathbf{v}, T(\mathbf{v}), \ldots, T^{n-1}(\mathbf{v})\right\}$ is linearly independent, and thus form a basis of $V .$ What are the eigenvalues of $T$ ?

I know how to show the linearly independent part
If $a_0 v + a_1 Tv +a _2 T^2v + \cdots + a_{m-1} T^{m-1}v=0$, then apply $T^{m-1}$ and get $a_0 T^{m-1}v=0$, which implies $a_0=0$. Now apply $T^{m-2}$ to get $a_1=0$. And so on.
So we can also conclude that these forms a basis.

But how to find the eigenvalues of $T$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Since $\;Tv=\lambda v\implies T^kv=\lambda^kv\;$, for $\;k\in\Bbb N\;,\,\,v\in V\;,\;\;\lambda\in\Bbb F=\;$ a scalar in the definition field, then in your case you'll get $\;0=T^nv=0=\lambda^nv\;$ , so...